# encoding string columns of dataset using python

Tags: python, datetime, artificial-intelligence, prediction

I have a dataset with 2 string columns with specific dates and times:

```
['10/10/2015 18:21' 'None' '7/10/1997 4:00' '12/05/1996 0:00''3/08/2016 14:30' '29/07/2002 0:00' '18/03/1997 0:00' '8/11/2014 7:41''14/09/2007 0:00' '22/11/2016 0:00' '11/10/2002 0:00' '14/11/2002 0:00' '16/07/2000 0:00' '25/05/2013 0:00' '9/08/1999 0:00' '15/09/2013 0:00']
```

I need to train a predicting model, so I need to covert these columns to a float.
so I first converted them to datetime

```
for col in ['WHOIS_REGDATE','WHOIS_UPDATED_DATE']:
    data[col] = pd.to_datetime(data[col],utc=True,  errors = 'coerce')
```

then I extracted the specific features, for day, month and year:

```
 data['Year_reg']=data['WHOIS_REGDATE'].apply(lambda dt: dt.year)
```

however I keep getting this error

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: first check if you really converted it to datetime - it seems you didn't do this and you still have strings.

Comment: I can't test it but maybe you need `lambda value: value.dt.year` instead of `lambda dt: dt.year`